# Strange PHP 5.3 issue with date diff calculating difference in days

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.3

I am experiencing a rather strange problem using PHP 5.3's date diff function to calculate the difference in days between two dates.  Below is my code:

```
$currentDate = new DateTime(); // (today's date is 2012-1-27)
$startDate = new DateTime('2012-04-01');

$diff = $startDate->diff($currentDate);

$daysBefore = $diff->d;

echo $daysBefore;
```

The above code displays 4 as the value of the $daysBefore variable.

Why is PHP displaying a difference of 4 days between the dates 27th Jan 2012 and 1st April 2012, when clearly there are many more days between these dates.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateInterval::$d` is the days part of the interval, **not** the total number of days of the difference.  For that, you want `DateInterval::$days`, so:

```
$daysBefore = $diff->days;
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval) through the [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method, it populates not just days, but hours, minutes, seconds, months and even years in the *single character* properties.  You're checking single-character `d` for days, which will be the days left over once years and months are calculated.

Try looking at the `days` property, which only actually gets populated when you use `diff`.

Behavior here is wildly inconsistent.  Check out the [`DateInterval::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) manual page for some interesting information about what happens when you create a DateInterval through various means.

Answer (score 2):

The `d` property is the number of days as in "3 months, **4 days**". If you want the *total* number of days, use the `days` property.

Answer (score 0):

4 days, and a couple months...

Use `$diff->days` for total number of days.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php